# How to check my privileges?

Tags: mysql, sql

How check my user privileges?

I am interested in privileges create user or grant privileges any users.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can check the privileges of the current user by running

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

Or the privileges of ANY user by running

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'user'@'host'
```

[Yay docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-grants.html)!